# Is there general rule to make noun from phrasal verb?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, suffixes

Like a rule to put an actor suffix like a **extinguish** -> **extinguisher** to make a noun from the verb to explain the actor of the action, is there any rule to make a noun of the actor of the action from a **phrasal verb**?

I've found an example as [Put-Outer](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/thing/put-outer/). I have deduced the following rule from this example.

1. Capitalize the first letters as **put out** -> **Put Out**.
2. Then, connect words by hyphen as **Put Out** -> **Put-Out**.
3. Put the actor suffix of the verb of a phrasal verb (like **er** of the verb **put**, which is the verb of phrasal verb **put out**) as **Put-Out** -> **Put-Outer**

Would you please tell me if my idea is correct? Thank you for your kind suggestion.

Comment: It's **extinguish** (two i's). _Put-outer_ isn't standard English. We can invent expressions like that in informal language, but you won't find them in the dictionary.

Comment: Thank you, Kate. I've fixed **extinguish**. Do you have any example nouns made from phrasal verbs?

Comment: An example that springs to mind is [picker-upper](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/picker-upper). The correct form would be _picker-up_ (the verb is the part that is modified), but in colloquial speech we sometimes humorously add '-er' to the end of the phrase as well.

Comment: I really appreciate your valuable suggestion, Kate. I've got my idea changed that there are no standard rules because nouns made from phrasal verbs are colloquial.

Comment: I've found following examples [cutter-off](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cutter-off#English), [cutter-offer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cutter-offer#English), [egger-on](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/egger-on#English), and [puller-outer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/puller-outer#English). Except for non-standard [Put-Outer](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/thing/put-outer/), it seems that the verb is the part that is modified, and humorously add '-er' to the end of the phrase as well as Kate suggested.

Comment: Note that three of these are marked _informal_. Compounds like this are pretty unusual in standard English. Shakespeare famously describes the character Autolycus as a 'snapper-up of unconsidered trifles', meaning that he helps himself to small items that their owners have left unguarded, and people sometimes invent similar expressions for use on a particular occasion.